# Configuring my NIC in Redhat

Tags: rhel

I am trying to set a larger buffer size in my NIC card. I am following the instruction provide by Intel [link](http://www.intel.com/support/network/adapter/pro100/sb/CS-032516.htm#parameters_e1000), but i think it didn't made any changes.

```
[root@redhat-enterprise-test01 admin]# rmmod e1000;modprobe e1000
[root@redhat-enterprise-test01 admin]# modprobe e1000 TxDescriptors=4096
[root@redhat-enterprise-test01 admin]# ethtool -g p1p1
Ring parameters for p1p1:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     4096
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:     256
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     256
[root@redhat-enterprise-test01 admin]# ethtool -i p1p1
driver: igb
version: 3.2.10-k
firmware-version: 1.5-1
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
```

Comment: Please add more info, and the image directly to the question. See [ask]?

Comment: How about also a copy of `/etc/modprobe.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file i.e `e1000.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d`, put some lines like this,

`e1000e RxDescriptors=4096`

the unload and reload the `e1000e` module with, i.e `rmmod e1000e; modprobe e1000e`

Later verify the parameter with `cat /sys/module/e1000e/parameters/RxDescriptors`.

This is not tested, my e1000e module is builtin.

**EDIT**

You could also add the following to `/etc/modprobe.conf`

```
options e1000 RxDescriptors=4096 <other options>
```

This is not the preferred way for newer systems but it is backward compatible depending on the version of RHEL you're running.

Comment: could you see my terminal result now? Am i basically did the same things as you suggested? it doesn't work could it because the name p1p1?

Answer (score 0):

So why not just

```
ethtool -G p1p1 rx 4096
```